# YouTube Data API, get channel subscriptions

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For research purposes I aim to retrieve the subscriptions of a number of YouTube channels, using the YouTube Data API. However, I am getting the error that I do not have the rights to see these subscriptions. Is there a way to get the required rights to see these subscriptions, and if so how?

Until now I've done some requests via Python to retrieve subscriptions of a channel. I have tried the code which is provided by the YouTube API tutorial itself, or a few wrappers. However for all I basically got the same message that I am not allowed to access this information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In https://www.youtube.com/account_privacy people can *keep all their subscriptions private* which is the case by default (it's the case of [`UCJ-pWgHZbdHV-mX8qcZc4nQ`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJ-pWgHZbdHV-mX8qcZc4nQ/channels) for instance). So for clear privacy reasons, you won't be able to retrieve their subscriptions.

However for some channels that switched this toggle, such as [`UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ/channels), their subscriptions are public and can be retrieved with [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) endpoint with the [`channelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#channelId) filter.